# Paypal Payflow Transparent Redirect Error Code: PL001

Tags: php, paypal, payflowpro

I am working on integrating a php payment form with Paypal Payflow using Transparent Redirect. I am getting the secure token OK but when I post the credit card information to https://pilot-payflowlink.paypal.com my browser displays this:

Error: There was a problem processing your request. If you continue to have an issue, please contact us. Error Code: PL001.

Here are the details of the token request:

To request the secure token, I posted the following to: https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com.

```
USER=**********
&VENDOR=***********
&PARTNER=PayPalUK
&PWD=************
&TRXTYPE=S
&TENDER=C
&CURRENCY=GBP
&CREATESECURETOKEN=Y
&SECURETOKENID=7og61wr3n8wbg2j866vqfken0r3izucof5k2
&SILENTTRAN=TRUE
&BILLTOFIRSTNAME=Dave
&BILLTOLASTNAME=Testing
&BILLTOSTREET=123 Some St
&BILLTOZIP=47374
&EMAIL=test@davefeltz.com
&AMT=1.00
```

I get a valid response back with RESULT=0 and SECURETOKEN=9fIJH6BNI80qLIV7cWdv5VQ9p

Then I post the credit card info to https://pilot-payflowlink.paypal.com with this form:

```
<form id="payment_form" name="payment_form" method="post" action="https://pilot-payflowlink.paypal.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="SECURETOKEN" value="9fIJH6BNI80qLIV7cWdv5VQ9p">
    <input type="hidden" name="SECURETOKENID" value="7og61wr3n8wbg2j866vqfken0r3izucof5k2">
    <input type="hidden" id="ACCT" name="ACCT" value="4242424242424242">
    <input type="hidden" id="EXPDATE" name="EXPDATE" value="022021">
    <input type="hidden" id="CSC" name="CSC" value="123">
</form>
```

https://pilot-payflowlink.paypal.com simply displays a page with the following:

Error: There was a problem processing your request. If you continue to have an issue, please contact us. Error Code: PL001.

Comment: "If you continue to have an issue, please contact us"  And did you contact them?

Comment: I think the "Contact us" message is for the website visitor so they know that something went wrong with their payment. I don't think it was meant for the developer. I posted the problem here hoping someone would know what is causing it so I can avoid a lengthy discussion with PayPal tech support.

Comment: did you ever find out anything about this? we're having the same issue

Comment: Anyone have an update on this issue? We’re experiencing the same thing and PayPal support hasn’t been much help. Have an open ticket but few updates.

Comment: This issue was from a long time ago but since I was just contacted by someone with the same problem I am going to post this update.

In my instance the client had a PayPal UK account and the problem
was that at least back then UK accounts did not support the
transparent redirect as US accounts did, thus generating the error. I don't recall the details because it was so long ago, but PayPal described a different way to
implement it as a hosted solution.

They sent me a PDF on how to implement the hosted solution for a UK account. Since it is a PDF I can't include it in this post.